# Convert local timestamp to unix epoch timestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

i have date string in below format(given in input) of local Asia/Calcutta timezone with(GMT+05:30) i want to convert it to gmt timezone and find epoch timestamp of that string.

**Input** : (in Local Time)
  **2019-11-09 10:10:10**

**Output** : (in GMT Time)
   **1573274410**

Comment: There's no such thing as a "local epoch timestamp". What do you think that is and how did you get it?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: added requirements in question, btw i found the solution

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.3+**:

```
import pytz 
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-09-30 09:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
ts = pytz.utc.localize(dt).timestamp()
```

Comment: i have epoch timestamp of local date string, and i want global date epoch timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is parse the time string correctly in the correct timezone, then get its timestamp:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

calcutta = timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
naive_ts = datetime.strptime('2019-11-09 10:10:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
local_ts = calcutta.localize(naive_ts)
epoch_ts = local_ts.timestamp()
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
timezone('Asia/Calcutta').localize(datetime.strptime('2019-11-09 10:10:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).timestamp()
```

The "GMT" is irrelevant here, the UNIX epoch `.timestamp()` is timezone independent. You can do `local_ts.timestamp()` and `local_ts.astimezone(pytz.utc).timestamp()`, they both result in the same number because they both express the exact same point in time (just in different locations on earth). All you need to do is turn your timestamp expressed as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS into an aware (including timezone) `datetime` object, then its `.timestamp()` will be the same no matter what timezone you convert it into.

Answer (score -2):

**I Found Solution**

input:(in Local Time)
   **2019-11-09 10:10:10**

output:(in GMT Time)
   **1573274410**

```
import calender
import time
from dateTime import dateTime

LocalTime = "2019-11-09 10:10:10"

GmtTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(LocalTime, timezone('Asia/Calcutta').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

GmtTimeStamp = calendar.timegm(time.strptime(str(GmtTime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

it solved my problem.

Comment: You're way overcomplicating this.

Comment: then give solution.